# How to use a custom template in ng-bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Here is the [ng-bootstrap typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) code:

```html
<div class="col">
  <input
    id="typeahead-config"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    [ngbTypeahead]="search"
    formControlName="searchText"
    [resultFormatter]="formatted"
    [inputFormatter]="formatter"/>
</div>
```

How do make changes to this dropdown?

[image]

I need to add a custom`<b>{{item.somevalue}}</b>` tags to that dropdown. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to use a custom popup HTML template when you type into the input?  In this example, they added flag image before the name of the state: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template

Comment: @skouch2022 thak you!

Comment: You are welcome. I updated your question to make it clearer for future users. You should always add as many details to your question as possible so it's easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@skouch2022 is right.

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
   your somevalue: <b>{{r['id']}}</b> <-- your b or i tag
   <ngb-highlight [result]="r.name" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the whole container template and not the template of a single row? (similar to the typeahead-popup-template-url that was supported for angularjs)